# Mistake in a matlab function which I couldn't identify

Tags: function, matlab, signals

I am newbie in matlab and writing a function code with the aim of helping to plot of half-wave rectified sine function. But it doesn't give me the result what I expect.

```
function x = rectifiedSineWave(t )
if sin(t) < 0
    x = 0;
else
    x = sin(t);
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `t` has just one element, your original code looks fine.

If `t` is a vector, you probably want

```
function x = rectifiedSineWave(t)
  x = sin(t);
  x(x<0)=0;
```

or, **even simpler** (thanks to [Serg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105037/serg))

```
function x = rectifiedSineWave(t)
  x = max(0, sin(t));
```

This way elements where `sin(t)` is negative are set to zero.

Your problem was that `if sin(t)<0` triggers as soon as *any* element of the vector `t` is negative, and will set `x` to zero.